# Prove existence of a basis given a matrix and a linear transformation describing matrix (Axler 3, #5)

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, linear-transformations

I have found an answer [here](https://linearalgebras.com/3c.html), but I found such answer to be unclear/unsatisfactory to me. So, I wrote out my own rationale and would like feedback on the proof.

**Problem Statement**

Suppose $w_1,...,w_n$ is a basis of $W$ and $V$ is finite-dimensional. Suppose the function $T$ is an element of the set of linear maps from $V$ to $W$. Prove that there exists a basis $v_1,...,v_m$ of $V$ such that all the entries in the first row of $M(T)$ (This notation refers to the matrix associated with T, with respect to the bases $v_1,...,v_m$ and $w_1,...,w_n$) are 0 except for possibly a 1 in the first row, first column.

*Proof.*

Let $M(T) = A$, where $A_{j,k}$ denotes the element in the $j^{th}$ row and $k^{th}$ column of the matrix.

Consider the case where the first row of $M(T)$ contains only $0$'s.
Then, by definition, $A_{1,1} = ... = A_{1,m} = 0$

If all of these coefficients are zero, then we have

$T(v_1) = 0 * w_1 + \sum_{j=2}^n A_{j,1}w_j$

$T(v_2) = 0 * w_1 + \sum_{j=2}^n A_{j,2}w_j$

...

$T(v_m) = 0 * w_1 + \sum_{j=2}^n A_{j,m}w_j$

So,

$T$ is linear $\implies T$ is additive

$T$ is additive $\implies T(v_1+...+v_m) = \sum_{i=1}^m( \sum_{j=2}^n A_{j,i}w_j)$

$T(v_1+...+v_m) = \sum_{i=1}^m( \sum_{j=2}^n A_{j,i}w_j) \implies range T = span(w_2,...,w_n)$

Choosing $v_1,...,v_m$ such that $T(v) = span(w_2,...,w_n), \forall v \in V$ gives M(T) such that all entries in the first row are $0$.

---

Now consider the case where the element in the first row, first column of $M(T)$ is 1.

Consider the case where we have $T(v_1) = w_1$.

We want to get rid of all $w_1$ for the other bases of $V$.

Notice:

$T(v_2) = \sum_{j=1}^n A_{j,2}w_j$

$T(v_2) - T(A_{1,2} * v_1) = \sum_{j=1}^n A_{j,2}w_j - T(A_{1,2}v_1)$

$T(v_2) - T(A_{1,2} * v_1) = \sum_{j=1}^n A_{j,2}w_j - A_{1,2}*T(v_1)$

$T(v_2) - T(A_{1,2} * v_1) = \sum_{j=1}^n A_{j,2}w_j - A_{1,2}*w_1$

$T(v_2) - T(A_{1,2} * v_1) = \sum_{j=2}^n A_{j,2}w_j$

$T(v_2 - A_{1,2} * v_1) = \sum_{j=2}^n A_{j,2}w_j$

So, we choose the list of vectors $(v_1, v_2 - A_{1,2}v_1, v_3 - A_{1,3}v_1,..., v_m - A_{1,m}v_1)$ as a basis for $V$ and then the condition that all entries are 0 in the first row except the entry in the first row, first column is satisfied, and the basis exists.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For the first part of the answer, I think you don't need to show $\text{range}~T = \text{span}~(w_2, \cdots, w_n)$. If for any basis of $V$, the first row of $M(T)$ only consists of zeros, then any basis of $V$ will meet the conditions of this question.

For the second part, you still need to show why $(v_1, v_2 - A_{1,2} v_1, \cdots, v_m - A_{1,m} v_1)$ is a basis of $V$; this, of course, is not difficult. we first show linear independence:

$$ \begin{align}
  b_1 v_1 + b_2 (v_2 - A_{1,2} v_1) + \cdots + 
  b_m (v_m - A_{1,m} v_1) & = 0 \\ 
  \implies (b_1 - \sum_{j=2}^m b_j A_{1,j}) v_1 +
  b_2 v_2 + \cdots + b_m v_m & = 0 \\
  \implies b_1 = b_2 = \cdots = b_m = 0
\end{align} $$

We can also obtain $v_2, \cdots, v_m$ as linear combinations of the suggested basis for $V$. So this new list is linearly independent and spans $V$, so it is a basis of $V$.